# How can I load a very large dictionary with JavaScript without freezing the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a spell-checking script that utilizes a long list of words. I formatted this large list of words as a JavaScript object, and I load the list as a script. So when it's loaded, that very big object is parsed.

*`dictionary.js`*

```
var dictionary = {
   "apple" : "apple",
   "banana" : "banana",
   "orange" : "orange"
}
```

Formatted this way for instant word validity checking:

```
if (dictionary["apple"]){
    //word is valid
}
```

The problem is that this giant object being parsed causes a significant DOM freeze.

<s>How can I load my data structure in a way so that I can parse it piece by piece?</s> How can I store/load my data structure so that the DOM can handle it without freezing?

Comment: Perhaps consider separating the list by starting letter or so.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read "How to ask". Did you think in order way to store your data instead memory?

Comment: @Leandro I know precisely how to ask questions on Stack Overflow. Did you find a problem with the way this question was asked?

Comment: Yes, indeed I comment because I think is a good question but someone downvoted you, and I think it happens for the same reason no body answer you. Here people preferes questions with at least one attempt, questions like "do my homework" or without researh are not good seen.

Comment: @Leandro I understand.. Well, I am not really sure where to start, I guess that's the case with questions sometimes..

Comment: Well techfoobar and I sent to you some help. I think is more an "algorythm" problem. You need cut your dictionary, or save it on some files, or database, or something related. In any way think in memory like a temporal thing. (sorry for my eng)

Comment: Maybe if you try, even with something grotesc, someone will be tell you "why don't you..."? There are a lot of refactor people :D

Comment: Did you consider Web Workers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: @ArnarYngvason wow... A web worker. How is it that I've never heard of this yet it's so profoundly useful..

Comment: This has nothing to do with the DOM. How long is the list of words? Did you consider an ajax query to do the lookup on the server?

Comment: @torazaburo interesting situation: this is for a user-script project. No server side. The list of words is 120K+

Comment: @torazaburo And it does have to do with the DOM because JavaScript's execution in a web page runs in the same place as the DOM. So if you task the page to parse a giant JavaScript object (a dictionary in this case), the DOM freezes until the array is finished loading (which is a big no-no).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your JS file in the form

```
var words = JSON.parse('{"aardvark": "aardvark", ...}');
```

JSON parse will be several orders of magnitude faster than the JS parser.

The actual lookup will be about 0.01ms by my measurement.

#### Background

There are several aspects to consider when thinking about performance in this situation, including download bandwidth, parsing, preprocessing or building if needed, memory, and retrieval. In this case, all other performance issues are overwhelmed by the JS parsing time, which could be up to 10 seconds for the 120K entry hash. If downloading from a server, the 2.5MB size could be an issue, but this will zip down to 20% or so of the original size. In terms of retrieval performance, JS hashes are already optimized for fast retrieval; the actual retrieval time might be less than 0.01ms, especially for subsequent accesses to the same key.  In terms of memory, there seem to be few ways to optimize this, but most browsers could hold an object this size without breaking a sweat.

The Patricia trie approach is interesting, and addresses mainly the memory usage and download bandwidth issues, but they do not seem in this case to be the main problem areas.

Comment: To answer your question and confusion, this JSFiddle will demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jdnmy9e8/1/ and the dictionary is being loaded in two object formats which means more like 240K words (complicated reason for this), but they are both loaded asynchronously via JQuery. One solution will be to build my own function for fuzzy string searching to avoid needing a separate dictionary format for spell checking and spell *suggesting*. But the 120K size still does cause a ~1 second DOM freeze. At least on my system, in Chrome, it does.

Comment: This is very interesting. Is `JSON.parse` so much faster than native parsing simply because JSON is a small subset of valid JS? Also, does that mean the performance gain would disappear if you were using an `eval`-polyfilled version of `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Yes it is, and yes it would.

Comment: Amadeus's patricia tree solution does save 3x the list size, but at the cost of 1/3 the lookup speed. I'm going to go with my own version of his answer, which parses it as JSON as suggested in this answer, but I'm accepting this one. Basically, the patricia tree makes sense if you're already going to be doing fuzzy string searching to fix spelling, but for the purpose of this question if you just want to load in a dictionary, this is the way to go.

Comment: After testing: [The object parsed as usual by js](http://jsfiddle.net/ypzekd02/3/) parses in 195ms. And [in JSON form](http://jsfiddle.net/ypzekd02/1/), as suggested in this answer, parses faster in 126ms. Results will vary from machine to machine but relativity generally won't.

Comment: I cannot believe how fast this is.

Answer (score 3):

If there are a *lot* of words in your list, one thing you can do to shrink the size of your dictionary is use a [patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree). A patricia trie is a special kind of tree optimized for searching for strings. Basically, each node in the trie is a single letter. So for instance:

```
var dictionary = {
    'a': {
        '': 1, // a
        'a': {
            '': 1, // aa
            'l': {
                '': 1, // aal
                'ii': 1 // aalii
            },
            'm': 1, // aam
            'ni': 1, // aani
            'r': {
                'd': {
                    'vark': 1, // aardvark
                    'wolf': 1 // aardwolf
                },
                'on': {
                    '': 1, // aaron
                    'ic': 1 // aaronic
                }
            }
        },
    },
}
```

In the above, I'm using the empty string '' (actually a valid property identifier!) to denote the end of a word.

Here's how you could implement the searching:

```
function isWord_internal(str, dic) {
    var strlen, i, substr, substrlen;
    strlen = str.length;
    for(i = strlen; i > 0; i--) {
        substr = str.slice(0, i);
        substrlen = substr.length;
        if(dic[substr]) {
            if(dic[substr] === 1) {
                if(substrlen === strlen) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false; // end of the line, folks
            }
            if(dic[substr][''] && substrlen === strlen) {
                return true;
            }
            return isWord_internal(str.slice(i), dic[substr]);
        } // else keep going
    }
    // not found
    return false;
}

function isWord(str) {
    return isWord_internal(str, dictionary); // assumes that the dictionary variable exists already
}
```

Since objects are hash tables O(log n) and the algorithm is linear with the size of a word, your performance should be O(n log n).

This should also keep the size of your list down, since English words are not random and often have substrings in common (you'll probably want to minify it though).

To convert your current dictionary, you can use this function to generate it in memory:

```
function patriciafy_internal(str, pat) {
    var i, substr, patkeys, patkeyslen, j, patkey, pos, portion;
    for(i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
        substr = str.slice(0, i);
        patkeys = Object.keys(pat);
        patkeyslen = patkeys.length;
        for(j = 0; j < patkeyslen; j++) {
            patkey = patkeys[j];
            pos = patkey.indexOf(substr);
            if(pos !== -1) {
                if(pat[patkey] !== 1) {
                    // keep going down the rabbit hole
                    patriciafy_internal(str.slice(i), pat[patkey]);
                } else {
                    // split this node and store the new key
                    portion = patkey.slice(0, pos + 1);
                    delete pat[patkey];
                    pat[portion] = {'': 1};
                    pat[portion][str.slice(1)] = 1;
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // no substring found - store the whole thing at this level
    pat[str] = 1;
}

function patriciafy(dic) {
    var pat, keys, keyslen, str, i;
    pat = {};
    keys = Object.keys(dic);
    keyslen = keys.length;
    for(i = 0; i < keyslen; i++) {
        // insert this str into the trie
        str = keys[i];
        patriciafy_internal(str, pat);
    }
    return pat;
}
```

Then just use `JSON.stringify` to print it out for use.

A test on my machine with a dictionary of 235,887 words (taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt)) showed that the Patricia tree was a little more than 1/3 smaller than a flat dictionary of the words, where the format of the flat dictionary was `{"name":1,"name2":1,...}`.

[image: Patricia tree: 2,296,106 characters, Flat dictionary: 3,419,872 characters]

This is still huge, but it's significantly less huge. You could probably also save a sizable amount of space by storing it in a non-JS format, e.g.

```
var dictionary = {
    'a': {
        '': 1,
        'a': {
            '': 1,
            'l': {
                '': 1,
                'ii': 1
            }
        }
    }
};
```

which minifies to

```
// 57 characters
var dictionary={'a':{'':1,'a':{'':1,'l':{'':1,'ii':1}}}};
```

could become

```
// 17 characters - single @ represents ''
@a{@@a{@@l{@@i}}}
```

which you would then parse.

=====

patricia-tree-to-@-syntax:

```
function patToAt_internal(pat) {
    var keys, i, s = "", key;
    s += "{";
    keys = Object.keys(pat);
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        key = keys[i];
        s += "@";
        s += key; // empty string will do nothing
        if(pat[key] !== 1) { // concat the sub-trie
            s += "{" + patToAt_internal(pat[key]) + "}";
        }
    }
    s += "}";
    return s;
}

function patToAt(pat) {
    return patToAt_internal(pat);
}
```

@-syntax-to-patricia-tree:

```
function atToPat_internal(at, pos) {

    var s = "", result, ff = true, ch;
    s += "{";
    pos++; // eat { character
    while((ch = at.charAt(pos)) !== "}") {
        // eat @ character
        pos++;
        // comma
        if(!ff) s += ",";
        else ff = false;
        // start key quote
        s += '"';
        // get the key
        while((ch = at.charAt(pos)) !== "@" && ch !== "{" && ch !== "}") {
            s += ch;
            pos++;
        }
        // close key quote and colon
        s += '":';
        // sub-trie
        if(ch === "{") {
            result = atToPat_internal(at, pos);
            s += result.s;
            pos = result.pos + 1;
        } else {
            s += "1";
        }
    }
    s += "}";
    return {pos: pos, s: s};

}

// this part is difficult, so we'll just delegate the heavy lifting to JSON.parse
function atToPat(at) {
    return JSON.parse(atToPat_internal(at, 0).s);
}
```

Using the @-syntax, the total size shrinks down to a third of the original flat dictionary:

[image]

**To sum up...**

Using this approach, you would build up the @-tree initially (just once) by doing

```
var dictionary = { ... } // your words here
// usually you can get all of the log if you triple click, or just output it into a textarea
console.log(patToAt(patriciafy(dictionary)));
```

and then once you've done that, on your page, you could do

```
var dictionary = atToPat("..."); // @-tree goes in the quotes

// and look up things like this:
isWord('apple');
```

Comment: You're probably correct that it would not improve performance vs a typical array, although the fact that it's so much smaller *might* actually improve performance if it allows more caching. With a giant dictionary like you've been using, you not only have a load-time performance hit, but you may experience [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29). I've added a function that should be close to optimal for searching the trie.

Comment: What do you mean by "get all of the words"?

Comment: Yeah... I was just looking into a way to automate the process. It's a little tricky but I'll let you know if I figure it out. Great question btw - it's a shame you were downvoted initially. It's not often you see questions that are actually somewhat fresh.

Comment: Well, your title is OK. A more appropriate answer would have been about gradually pulling in pieces of the dictionary through AJAX calls, but I didn't think that was so good performance-wise, so I gave this answer instead. It's really my answer which is off, not your question. But you could change it to something like "How can I more efficiently store a dictionary?" if you wanted.

Comment: Just fixed a bug in the `patriciafy` function - works now. In my initial tests, the patricia tree is bigger than a plain dictionary, but I'm hoping that the balance will shift when the number of words gets really large. If not, sorry it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried it with a list of 200K+ here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt and the Patricia tree was about 1.5x bigger. Oh well. I think that storing longer segments of the strings could make it work, but that's a lot more difficult to code. Pulling in pieces at a time through AJAX calls and/or using as Arnar suggested in the comments is probably your best bet. Feel free to uncheck this answer. I'll leave it up for now in case I figure out how to save it.

Comment: Ok, I tested this in depth, running different word lengths and starting letters 10,000 times each, using `consoleTime()`. This method does slightly decrease the size of my 120K word dictionary by 0.15MB. It also, however, roughly triples the processing time to test a word's validity.

Comment: Please leave this answer here though; this method might actually be better for getting word suggestions via fuzzy string searching. So I may yet use this instead. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: After a lot of thinking and reading, I realized that my initial implementation of a patricia tree wasn't quite right. I have a new implementation that actually cuts down storage space by about a third. I'll post the changes now.

Comment: @me when you post them.

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer Sorry, took longer than I thought it would. Managed to get the size down to 1/3 the original! But I think the solution given by torazaburo is better as long as the performance gain is consistent. It was a fun ride anyway.

Comment: I can actually combine the three solutions: This -> expand to JSON format with a simple function -> parse as JSON -> all inside a web worker. Viola. The ultimate solution to size, speed, and DOM performance for loading a large dictionary in JavaScript. You're probably burnt out on this answer, but if you want a completionist cape, you could borrow those last two parts in your answer.

Comment: Ohh, there was still the performance side of this as well. Does your new tree change lookup speed? Because on the older version I tested it at 3x the lookup time of a keyed array. I think this answer boils down to whether or not you want to suggest words, or just check them. If you want to suggest them, then this table is great for fuzzy string searching. But if you want to just check them nothing beats an associative list's speed due to JS's use of hash tables to store the values.